# hiding uitoolbar leaves gap between view and tab bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, ios7, xcode5

I have an application with 3 tabs. The first tab loads the navigation controllers toolbar. If i switch tab, or go to another view without the toolbar in the same tab, then i'm left with a gap at the bottom between the view and the toolbar, thats the same height as the toolbar.

How do i make the view full screen. This doesn't happen on ios6, just ios7

I'm creating the toolbar programatically as so

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *print = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Print", @"Print button") style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(showPrint:) ];
    UIBarButtonItem *email = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Email", @"Email button") style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(showEmail:) ];

    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: print, email, nil];
    [self setToolbarItems: buttons animated:NO];
    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:FALSE];
}
```

and hiding it like such

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toAddMed"])
    {
        [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Turns out when i created the scene, the constraints hadn't been created so the view wasn't auto resizing, adding the missing constraints fixed the problem

Comment: Can you elaborate on that solution? I'm running into a very similar problem.

Comment: I had to select the view i wanted in the storyboard then go

Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset To Suggested Constraints